# error: result_array() on boolean with sqlsrv ajax method

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014, and I already configured everything on CI, I dont know why is this happening but it really did bother me alot.

I got a stored procedure and that is what I will use in, for example my stored procedure is:

```
 create procedure [dbo].[set_add_user_i]
  @firstname varchar(50),
  @lastname varchar(50)
 as
 begin try
   insert into [Users](Firstname,Lastname)
   values(@firstname,@lastname)
 end try
 begin catch
   select 'Error' as result;
 end catch
```

Then in my CI_Model

```
 public function set_add_user($param){
    $query = $this->db->query("exec set_add_user_i
                                                    '".$param["firstname"]."',
                                                    '".$param["lastname"]."'
                                                    ");


    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I use exec as to call the stored procedure and put the parameters from the @firstname and @lastname

Then in my CI_Controller

```
 public function add_user(){
    $data = $this->My_Model->set_add_user( array(
        'firstname' => trim($this->input->post('firstname')),
        'lastname'  => trim($this->input->post('lastname'))
    ));

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This is to call the post data from my view using ajax method I did this thing:

```
    AddUsers                                    : function (e,data)                     {

        var $tmp = ( typeof(e) == 'object' ) ? 1 : 2,
            $self = AddUser.config;

        if($self.txt_add_last_name.val() == ''){
            $self.txt_add_last_name.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if($self.txt_add_first_name.val() == ''){
            $self.txt_add_first_name.focus();
            return false;
        }           

        switch($tmp) {
          case 1: 
            var $data = {
                'firstname'  : $self.txt_add_first_name.val(),
                'lastname'   : $self.txt_add_last_name.val()
            };
            AddUser.CallAjax('add_user', $data, 1); 

          break; 
          case 2:
            alert('User Successfully Added!');

          break;        
        }
    },
    CallAjax                                    : function (url, data, type)            { 
            var $self = AddUser.config;
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(evt){ 
                            console.log(evt);
                            if(evt){
                                    switch(type){
                                            case 1: AddUser.AddUsers(2,evt); break;
                                    }    
                            }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                    }
            });                 
    }
```

The first function is the event click which will get the controller method add_user and the data are inside the $data variables, and then passes it to the Callajax function which i put case 1 on the callajax and (2,evt) will get it back to case 2: of the AddUsers function but when I clicked it, it will show me

Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Is there something wrong with it? cause without it, it will not go to the callajax function since it doesnt have return value. I need some help. Thank you very much